# child route with outlet redirecting to 404 component

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have a parent component on route `/social-wall/5e9fd94aa7a7442fc8d126c7` and I need to invoke a child component(modal) that is lazily loaded on route `/social-wall/5e9fd94aa7a7442fc8d126c7/(upload:5edf40a0c7762c3f5062e6e1)` and I try invoking child in programmatical way on route `/social-wall/5e9fd94aa7a7442fc8d126c7/(upload:5edf40a0c7762c3f5062e6e1)` but it is redirecting to 404 component.there is no failed API calls and no errors neither in developer tools nor in VS code terminal. I have tried debugging it but didn't succeed. I dont know what i am doing wrong and I have been stuck in this for the past 36 hours. any help is very much appreciated.

parent.component.ts

```
 this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { upload: this.selectedUploadQuestion.answer._id } }],{ relativeTo: this.route });
```

parent.component.html

```
<router-outlet name="upload"></router-outlet>
```

parent.module.ts

```
const routes = [
{ path: ':id', component: SocialWallComponent, pathMatch: 'full', children: [
    { path: ':upload-id', loadChildren: '../shared/question/upload-question/upload-question.module#UploadQuestionModule', outlet: "upload" },
]}
]
 @NgModule({
   imports: [ CommonModule,RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
   declarations: [SocialWallComponent],
   providers:[SocialWallService]
})
```

child.module.ts

```
const routes = [
{ path: '', component: UploadQuestionComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }]

@NgModule({
   exports: [ UploadQuestionComponent, RouterModule ],
   imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes)
})


export class UploadQuestionModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your syntax to lazy load the child-module is wrong but I'm not sure if that is causing the problem. The definition of the route in your `parent.module.ts` should look like this:

```js
{
    path: ':upload-id',
    loadChildren: () => import(
        '../shared/question/upload-question/upload-question.module'
    ).then(m => m.UploadQuestionModule),
    outlet: 'upload'
}
```